# Why the SequenceFile is truncated?

Tags: java, hadoop, sequencefile

I am learning `Hadoop` and this problem has baffled me for a while. Basically I am writing a `SequenceFile` to disk and then read it back. However, every time I get an `EOFException` when reading. A deeper look reveals that when writing the sequence file, it is prematurely truncated, and it always happens after writing index 962, and the file always has a fixed size of 45056 bytes.

I am using Java 8 and Hadoop 2.5.1 on a MacBook Pro. In fact, I tried the same code on another Linux machine under Java 7, but the same things happens.

I can rule out writer/reader is not properly closed. I tried using the old styled try/catch with an explicit writer.close() as shown in the code, and also use the newer try-with-resource approach. Both are not working.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Following is the code I am using:

```
public class SequenceFileDemo {

private static final String[] DATA = { "One, two, buckle my shoe",
    "Three, four, shut the door",
    "Five, six, pick up sticks",
    "Seven, eight, lay them straight",
    "Nine, ten, a big fat hen" };

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String uri = "file:///Users/andy/Downloads/puzzling.seq";
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);

    Path path = new Path(uri);      
    IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
    Text value = new Text();

    //API change
    try {
        SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf, 
            stream(fs.create(path)),
            keyClass(IntWritable.class),
            valueClass(Text.class));

        for ( int i = 0; i < 1024; i++ ) {
            key.set( i);
            value.clear();
            value.set(DATA[i % DATA.length]);

            writer.append(key, value);
            if ( (i-1) %100 == 0 ) writer.hflush();
            System.out.printf("[%s]\t%s\t%s\n", writer.getLength(), key, value);
        }

        writer.close();

    } catch (Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(conf, 
                SequenceFile.Reader.file(path));
        Class<?> keyClass = reader.getKeyClass();
        Class<?> valueClass = reader.getValueClass();

        boolean isWritableSerilization = false;
        try {
            keyClass.asSubclass(WritableComparable.class);
            isWritableSerilization = true;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

        }

        if ( isWritableSerilization ) {
            WritableComparable<?> rKey = (WritableComparable<?>) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(keyClass, conf);
            Writable rValue = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(valueClass, conf);
            while(reader.next(rKey, rValue)) {
                System.out.printf("[%s] %d %s=%s\n",reader.syncSeen(), reader.getPosition(), rKey, rValue);
            }
        } else {
            //make sure io.seraizliatons has the serialization in use when write the sequence file
        }

        reader.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce this on Windows 8, Java 8 and Hadoop 2.2 as well- even when just writing the integers. Interesting bug you found there. And it actually seems to truncate the file towards the end for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the error, it is because you are never closing the created stream in `Writer.stream(fs.create(path))`.

For some reason the close doesn't propagate down to the stream you just created there. This is a bug I suppose, but I'm too lazy to look it up in Jira for now.

One way to fix your problems is to simply use `Writer.file(path)` instead.

Obviously, you can also just close the create stream explicitly. Find my corrected example below:

```
    Path path = new Path("file:///tmp/puzzling.seq");

    try (FSDataOutputStream stream = fs.create(path)) {
        try (SequenceFile.Writer writer = SequenceFile.createWriter(conf, Writer.stream(stream),
                Writer.keyClass(IntWritable.class), Writer.valueClass(NullWritable.class))) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
                writer.append(new IntWritable(i), NullWritable.get());
            }
        }
    }

    try (SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(conf, Reader.file(path))) {
        Class<?> keyClass = reader.getKeyClass();
        Class<?> valueClass = reader.getValueClass();

        WritableComparable<?> rKey = (WritableComparable<?>) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(keyClass, conf);
        Writable rValue = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(valueClass, conf);
        while (reader.next(rKey, rValue)) {
            System.out.printf("%s = %s\n", rKey, rValue);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas! I verified the fix and it works. In addition, your answer prompts to look at the source code. When creating the writer, if we pass in the option **Writer.file(path)**, the writer "owns" the underlying stream created internally, and will close it when close() is called. Yet if we pass in **Writer.stream(aStream)**, the writer assumes someone else is response for that stream and won't close it when close() is called.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing writer.close() after write loop. That should gaurantee a final flush before you start reading.

Comment: Thanks but it is not the case. I've added the close() before thinking exactly the same, yet it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas.

It boils down to if the writer created "owns" the stream of not. When creating the writer, if we pass in the option **Writer.file(path)**, the writer "owns" the underlying stream created internally, and will close it when close() is called. Yet if we pass in **Writer.stream(aStream)**, the writer assumes someone else is response for that stream and won't close it when close() is called. In short, it is not a bug, just that I do not understand it well enough. .