# image added in hadoop sequence file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, sequencefile

I am trying to run java program on my hadoop system to store image in sequence file and then trying to read that sequence file after that.
My Sequence is created but image data is not getting appended in sequence file.

I am trying to run below code by running this command

sudo -u hdfs hadoop jar /usr/java_jar/ImageStorage.jar ImageStorage 12e2baa2ae0e455ac40015942b682c4b.jpg

Please help me out here.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.Writer.Option;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;

public class ImageStorage {
   private static void openOutputFile(String args1) throws Exception {
    String uri = "hdfs://localhost:8020/";

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
    Path path = new Path("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/img_data/SequenceFileCodecTest.seq");

    String string1 = "hdfs://localhost:8020/user/img_data/";
    string1 = string1 + args1;

    Path inPath = new Path(string1);

    FSDataInputStream in = null;
    Text key = new Text();
    BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
    SequenceFile.Writer writer = null;
    try{
        in = fs.open(inPath);
        byte buffer[] = new byte[in.available()];
        in.read(buffer);
        System.out.println(buffer);
        in.close();

        Option optPath = SequenceFile.Writer.file(path);
        Option optKey = SequenceFile.Writer.keyClass(key.getClass());
        Option optVal = SequenceFile.Writer.valueClass(value.getClass());
        Option optCom = SequenceFile.Writer.compression(SequenceFile.CompressionType.BLOCK);
        FSDataOutputStream fileOutputStream = fs.append(path);
        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));

        writer.append(new Text(inPath.getName()), new BytesWritable(buffer));
        br.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception MESSAGES = "+e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(writer);
        System.out.println("last line of the code....!!!!!!!!!!");

    }




  }

   private static void openReadFile() throws Exception {
     String uri = "hdfs://localhost:8020/";

     Configuration conf = new Configuration();
     FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
     Path path = new Path("hdfs://localhost:8020/user/img_data/SequenceFileCodecTest.seq");
     /* Reading Operations */

     org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.Reader.Option filePath = SequenceFile.Reader.file(path);
     SequenceFile.Reader sequenceFileReader = new SequenceFile.Reader(conf,filePath);

     Writable key1 = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(
            sequenceFileReader.getKeyClass(), conf);
     Writable value1 = (Writable) ReflectionUtils.newInstance(
            sequenceFileReader.getValueClass(), conf);

     try {

        while (sequenceFileReader.next(key1, value1)) {
            System.out.printf("[%s] %s %s \n", sequenceFileReader.getPosition(), key1,value1.getClass());
        }
     } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(sequenceFileReader);
     }
     /* Reading operations */

}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    openOutputFile(args[1]);
    openReadFile();
}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why the SequenceFile is truncated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916872/why-the-sequencefile-is-truncated)

Comment: Thanks but it is not the case.

Comment: It is, because you are closing the writer, but not the `in`.

Comment: I added in.close but still no success.I am new to this stuff.

Comment: I update the code also

Comment: Now you are not closing the `br` and `fileOutputStream`.

Comment: I also done what you had said but still no success.I update the code also above.